# How to turn autocomplete into a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am calling jquery autocomplete several times on my form. How can I refactor and the following javascript into a function?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Style").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Beer/AutoStyle",
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.Style,
                                value: item.Style
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

I cannot figure out how to paramterize the this

```
    return {
           label: item.Style,
           value: item.Style
    }
```

So my function would be something like this

```
  function AutoCompleteTemplate(tagID){
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#"+tagID).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Auto"+tagID,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.tagID,
                                value: item.tagID
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: You don't need the `$(document).ready(function () {` inside your functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) as the [member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators), since `tagID` is a variable holding the actual property key

```
function AutoCompleteTemplate(tagID) {
    $("#" + tagID).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Auto" + tagID,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item[tagID],
                            value: item[tagID]
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```